# ANSI color codes are messing up my output randomly in C

Tags: c, colors, printf, ansi-escape

I'm using ANSI code to color text within the terminal, it works great except in loop, `printf` ramdomly displays the ANSI code itself:

```
#define RED "\x1B[31m"
#define BLU "\x1B[34m"
#define RST "\x1B[0m"
for
{
   printf(RED "red text\n" BLU "blue text" RST);
}
```

And I get randomly:

```
red text // text displayed in red 
   [34m blue text // still in red
```

Or:

```
red text //text displayed in red
blue text // text displayed in blue
```

I tried to separate color declaration and text in two different `printf`, I tried to use `puts` but it was useless. I don't use `ncurse` library because I think that it is not suitable for this case. By the way, I'm using CLion on MACOS 10.12 if it can help. I found some solutions like [Charles Campbell's ANSI escape code](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) but not adapted for C.

Why ANSI codes are messing up, and how could we possibly fix it ?

Comment: Are you running your program in `Terminal.app`, or are you using the CLion embedded terminal?

Comment: I am currently using the Clion embedded terminal.

Comment: Try running your code from `Terminal`.

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742850/how-to-show-colored-console-output-in-clion).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion this thread. I tried to run my code from `Terminal.app`but I got a linker problem since my code is separated in different files.