# CLion C99 how do i output in colour to the console

Tags: c, colors, printf, clion, c99

I want to print text in colour in CLion, it works when I use other IDEs but not Clion, can someone help please

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
printf("\033[0;32m");
printf("Hello, World!\n");
return 0;
}
```

for example the code above just outputs

```
?[0;32mHello, World!
```

instead of printing the text in green

Comment: Possible dupe of [How to show colored console output in Clion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742850).

Comment: @IanAbbott yes i read though that and the answers didn't solve anything, Also it was 5 years ago and for C++

Comment: Still, it seems to be a limitation or bug in CLion rather than a problem in your code.